# Append <th> Class to <td> in the Same Column

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, html-table

I've been searching all over the net for hours now but I still can't figure this out.

```
<table>  
  <tr>  
    <th class="name">Name</th>
    <th class="age">Age</th>
    <th class="nick">Nick</th>
  </tr>  

  <tr>  
    <td>John</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>Johnny</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>  
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>Bob</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way to append the classes from those headers to the TD tags in the same column?

Comment: Did you consider using the COL element? It works the same way, but without javascript. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
$("table th").each(function(i, val) {
  var th = $(this);
  var selector = "td:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")";
  th.parent().siblings().find(selector).attr("class", th.attr("class"));
});
```

It uses the [`:nth-child` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild#index) to effectively get the same `<td>` in the same column. It breaks down if you use rowspan/colspan elements however.

**Note:** you have to add one to the index because the index on `each()` is zero-based but `:nth-child()` is one-based.

Also, you can't use the `:eq` selector in this context as it only matches a single element.

Comment: Works. Thanks! By the way, you forgot a ")" in the first line.