# Append <th> with <td> using repeater in same column

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I am rendering the data using repeater on web page, however the data isn't displaying in the correct order.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeatInformation" runat="server">  
        <HeaderTemplate>
<table id="tbldata" border="1" cellspacing="0" rules="all">  
        <tr style= "background-color: #eee;">
            <th scope="col" style="width: 90px">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">09:00</th>
            <th scope="col">09:30</th>
            <th scope="col">10:00</th>
            <th scope="col">10:30</th>
            <th scope="col">11:00</th>
            <th scope="col">11:30</th>
            <th scope="col">12:00</th>
            <th scope="col">12:30</th>
            <th scope="col">13:00</th>
            <th scope="col">13:30</th>
            <th scope="col">14:00</th>
            <th scope="col">14:30</th>
            <th scope="col">15:00</th>
            <th scope="col">15:30</th>
            <th scope="col">16:00</th>
            <th scope="col">16:30</th>
            <th scope="col">17:00</th>
            <th scope="col">17:30</th>
            <th scope="col">18:00</th>
        </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <tr>  
                <td><%# Eval("Date") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time1") %></td>  
                <td><%# Eval("Time2") %></td>  
                <td><%# Eval("Time3") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time4") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time5") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time6") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time7") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time8") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time9") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time10") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time11") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time12") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time13") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time14") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time15") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time16") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time17") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Time18") %></td> 
                <td><%# Eval("Time19") %></td>
            </tr> 
                </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have been tried to do it using the below script which I take referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829508/append-th-class-to-td-in-the-same-column).

```
<%--<script>
        $("#tbldata th").each(function (i, val) {
            var th = $(this);
            var selector = "td:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")";
            th.parent().siblings().find(selector).attr("#tbldata", th.attr("#tbldata"));
        });
    </script>--%>
```

[Currently the data is showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfp1y.png)

Someone please suggest me how can I show the data in correct order column wise.

Comment: Please explain what the correct order would be.

Comment: the value should be shown below the each column. Like I can say for each <th> one <td>

Comment: You are creating multiple tables, you no that right? a `table` in the HeaderTemplate and one in the ItemTemplate. And maybe use a GridView, which is a table?

Comment: As @VDWWD says, you're creating two tables, so the table with the actual data doesn't have the same column widths as the one above it.

Comment: But how can I use both the headers and data within the same table?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have been tried to do it now with the use of one table and the first row is populating the data fine but the rest of the rows aren't populating correctly. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You're not properly explaining the difference between what you want and what you see.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please check the image which I have posted. I want all the rows display like the first row where the date is 04-11-2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the closing `</table>` tag from the `<ItemTemplate>` to the `FooterTemplate`:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```